# Physical push-down toggle button that pops up on voltage

Tags: transistors, switches, physical-design

I have encountered innumerable variations to functionally identical 2-lead physical switches, like the push-to-toggle buttons I am currently working with. Manually depressing the button toggles between two alternate states, popped up and pressed down, each of which physically separates and bring into contact the conductors, respectively.

Does there exist a widely-available 3-lead variation of the described switch that physically pops the switch up when the trigger lead is supplied current, and what it it called?

Comment: Never seen one with 3 leads. 2 leads all the time though.

Answer (score 1):

It's a rocker, not a toggle, but [this switch](http://www.components.omron.com/components/web/pdflib.nsf/0/B796977D25C035D286257B94006FF827/$file/A8GS_0613.pdf) has a reset coil.

[image]

It has an 11\$\Omega\$ 5V coil that requires that you limit the on time to 50~100ms maximum on and at least 5 seconds off (2% duty cycle).

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something that does work a bit like that, but not exactly. It's a **no-volt dropout** or zero-volt dropout switch. It's like a normal switch (a rocker switch in the type that I've seen) in that it has two positions, on and off, and will stay put in either of them. But, it only stays in the ON position if there's a power supply (from the mains). If the mains supply fails, the switch "drops out" to the OFF position and stays there until mains power is restored and the user presses the switch again.

So, it's backwards compared to what you want, I think. Maybe there's some way you could modify one or use a lack of power to trigger it?